# Hibernate+ postgres batch update does not work

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Is there any way to do batch updates ?

i create a simple entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class A {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "A_ID_GENERATOR")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "A_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "a_id_seq")
  private Long id;

  private String name;
}
```

next step i generated 10000 objects of class A and put them to db

next step i get list of A from db ,set new name and save them again

```
  @PutMapping
  @Transactional
  public String updateAllTest(){
    var list=aRepository.findAll();

    for (int i = 0; i <list.size() ; i++) {
      list.get(i).setName("AA"+i);

    }
    return "OK";
  }
```

what did i expect- i expect that hibernate will do batch update
and hibernate did it -hibernate statistics says - it execute 200 batches ( batch size=500)

next i go to db log files  and what i see there- there are no batches- only single updates -10 000 rows

it looks like same with batch insert without adding reWriteBatchedInserts=true to JDBC driver

so is there any way to do batch updates in postgres with hibernate or no?

Comment: Not if you haven't configured hibernate to do batch updates, you need to set a batch size, ordering of insert/update statements and in the end your database needs to support it (which may require tweaking settings on the Jdbc driver). Finally using `@Transactional` on a controller isn't the best way, move it to a service instead (might even be that this `@Transactional` is being ignored in the end).

Comment: hibernate is configured to do batch inserts/updates .i have this config in application.yaml   hibernate:jdbc:
        batch_size: 500
        fetch_size: 1000
      order_inserts: true
      order_updates: true

Comment: @transactioanal on controler is typical way if you do not use open-in-view in spring boot

Comment: if i move @transactional to service - i will never do it in same transaction cuz hibernate will do dirtry check all of these findAll and saveAll will be in same transaction or you will be lose this game ;)

Comment: You have to move everything to the service method. Using `@Transactional` on a controller can lead to surprising effects and hard to debug issues especially when mapping stops working (due to the proxy being created). Please don't add additional information in comments, instead edit your question. And it isn't really a typical way as that basically is more or less the same as open-in-view (but that is a whole other discussion).

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand is that reusing the same server side statement handle for multiple executions is batching. The log is just telling you about every execution, but that doesn't mean it is slow. It's doing exactly what it should do.